# Auto addition of text within cells of column A if one enters a number in the same cell of the column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am complete novice in Google script, but have a little bit of knowledge of spreadsheet formula and function.

I need that if my user enter any number in a cell in column A (say, 123 in A1), it automatically gives out in the same cell (as a drop-down list) two options - **LAPL/2K17/123** and **LA/2K17/123** - to choose from.

I don't think it is possible to achieve through spreadsheet funcions, is it even possible through Google Script as the same cell in which the data is being entered has to have the changed text?

Answer (score 1):

here is an option- not exactly what you are looking for, however it may function for you.

```js
function onEdit(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var resp = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
for(var n=0;n<resp.length;n++)
{ 
  for(var p=0;p<resp[n].length;p++)
  {
    if(resp[n][p].toString().match(/^123/)) { 
      
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'LAPL/2K17/123?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    ui.alert('Setting Value to LAPL/2K17/123');
    ss.getRange(n+1,p+1).setValue('LAPL/2K17/123') 
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ss.getRange(n+1,p+1).setValue('LA/2K17/123') 
    ui.alert('Setting Value to LA/2K17/123');
  }
      
      
    };
  }
}};
```

Comment: Yea, it's a good workaround, even better. Thanx! 

Just one issue though - i gave 123 just as an example only... it could be any number but the script is currently outputing 123 only. It should dynamically change the number accroding to the input.

That means, if the number entered in the cell A10 is 892, the script should give the options of LAPL/2K17/892 and LA/2K17/892. Sorry, i was not clear enough in my above post.

Comment: I think if the above answer is an answer for your initial question you can mark it as answered and create a new post with your supplied code regarding the 2nd part.